# How to simplify $\frac{1+h^{-1}e^{-z}}{1+he^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know it should be  $h^{-1}e^{-z}$ but I don't know how to show the algebra for that. I am guessing there might be something to do with partial fractions or series expansions, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Multiply by $\dfrac{he^z}{he^z}$; multiply out the numerator and leave the product in the denominator.

Comment: (An easier way to see this, perhaps, is to just set $w=he^z$ and note that your original fraction is $\dfrac{1+w^{-1}}{1+w}$; then the hint is just multiplying by $\frac ww$.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tend to be fine with the concepts on my homework, but its things like this that I tend to get stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this clearer, let $x=he^z$. Your expression can be expressed as 
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+x}=\frac{\frac{x+1}{x}}{1+x}=\frac{x+1}{x(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x}=h^{-1}e^{-z}$$